# Preserve space after delimeter regex

Tags: regex

I have the next regex which keeps "c" and delimiter sign from replacement

```
(?<=c[:=\s]|:=).+
```

But the problem is in case of spaces after delimiter, it replaces them as well:

```
c= test1
```

will replace for example with:

```
c=test
```

How can I preserve space after delimiter sign in order it will not be replaced:

```
c= test
```

I have tried the next:

```
(?<=c[:=\s]\s).+
```

But in it doesn't do matching and correct replacement for strings which do not contain a space after delimiter:

```
c=test1
```

Comment: What language are you doing the Regex in? JavaScript, Python, Java? I'd tinker around via this website. https://regex101.com/

Comment: I use python3 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match c followed by : or = and zero or more whitespace characters `\s+` and then capture one or more characters in a group (.+). Start with a word boundary `\b` to make sure `c` is not part of a longer match.

As replacement you could use the first capturing group `\1` followed by your replacement text.

**Match**

[`\b(c[:=]\s*).+`](https://regex101.com/r/aEOjn6/1)

**Replace with**

`\1test`

[`Demo Python`](http://rextester.com/JNU11895)

Comment: Thank you, but that's not that I want. I have two cases: 1. text or any other sequence which is followed by delimiter(= or :) is being replaced, but delimeter and variable name are preserved: c=test1 (matching here is test1 only). 2. When there is a space after delimiter. In this case variable name, delimeter and space are being peserved but sequence or text followed after are being replaced: c= test1 (matching here will be test1 only).

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as expected. Could you please tell what is \1 in replacement?

Comment: That is the first [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Comment: Thank you! And have a great evening/day!